# Got problems with replacing xml nodes within text

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on XML-to-XML transformation (Windows 10, Oxygen XML Editor) and got this task: replace `<xref id="id1">text</xref>` with `id1`.

I've done some work but can't get why doesn't scenario replace all xref-s in parentheses. Any ideas?

And just in case if somebody know how to remove parentheses outside of xref-s, please tell. I was trying `concat('(',$temp,')')` but it also skips parenteses and `concat('(',$temp,';')` even doesn't work.

**Here the example** (I keep punctuation just in case):

```
<section>
    <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id1">TEXT1, 2014</xref>) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id5">TEXT5., 2016</xref>) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id6">TEXT6., 2004</xref>; <xref id="id7">TEXT7., 2014</xref>; <xref id="id8">TEXT8., 2012</xref>), dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id6">TEXT6., 2004</xref>; <xref id="id7">TEXT7., 2014</xref>; <xref id="id8">TEXT8., 2012</xref>), dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
...
```

**Here the result**:

```
<section>
    <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id1) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id5) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id6; TEXT7., 2014; TEXT8., 2012), dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (TEXT6., 2004; id7; TEXT8., 2012), dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
...
```

**I expect**:

```
<section>
    <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id1) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id5) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id6; id7; id8), dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (id6; id7; id8), dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
...
```

and **Here the scenario**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template name="xrefs">
    <xsl:for-each select="section">
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <xsl:variable name="tempP">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="xref">
                <xsl:variable name="temp">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace($tempP,$temp,./@id)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="xrefs"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the exact result you expect to get here? The output you show is not well-formed XML, and it makes very little sense: why is `TEXT7` preserved, but `TEXT1` is not?

Comment: I've done some improvements. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: I think I did. However,  I am not sure if you can use XSLT 2.0 for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> got this task: replace `<xref id="id1">text</xref>` with `id1`.

That could be done easily by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applies to the following **well-formed (!)** input example:

**XML**

```
<section>
    <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id1">TEXT1, 2014</xref>) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id5">TEXT5., 2016</xref>) dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id6">TEXT6., 2004</xref>; <xref id="id7">TEXT7., 2014</xref>; <xref id="id8">TEXT8., 2012</xref>), dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum (<xref id="id6">TEXT6., 2004</xref>; <xref id="id7">TEXT7., 2014</xref>; <xref id="id8">TEXT8., 2012</xref>), dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
   <p>Lorem ipsum (id1) dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum (id5) dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum (id6; id7; id8), dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum (id6; id7; id8), dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
```

---

> And just in case if somebody know how to remove parentheses outside of
>   xref-s, please tell.

That could be achieved by adding these two templates (requires XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[self::xref]][ends-with(., '(')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length() - 1) "/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[self::xref]][starts-with(., ')')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2) "/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <somenode>Lorem ipsum</somenode>
   <p>Lorem ipsum id1 dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum id5 dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum id6; id7; id8, dolor.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum id6; id7; id8, dolor.</p>
    ...
</section>
```

Comment: Oops. So I'll type in one line. As for your first code it just removes all xref-s and doesn't place xref's id. So the second I'll try later, it's not the main task but thanks I'll try it.

Comment: You can now see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVc and: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVc/1

Comment: Well @michael.hor257k it's just the code in my post not well formed (I've already edited it). I work in Oxygen it won't let me to transform documents with such errors. And sorry I've made a typo right in id when was trying your code :). Your code works. Thanks. I'll close the question.